# Looking for a geometric cosmology model where time behaves like an orientation

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, geometry

[image]

This question is literally inspired from seeing the above scene unfold.

Let the merging and splitting light spots you saw in the above gif be pairs of particles and anti particles, let the shape of the showerheads be the curvature of some region of spacetime, let the visual panning you saw here be the time axis.

Thus is there any cosmological model in the literature that behaves something like this description? :

The particle antiparticle pairs you saw are actually geometric features of some underlying physical object, where time behaves like a rotation such that a slightly different orientation of the physical object is seen. The projections of this geometric object under different angles then produce what we observed as particle anti particle pairs

In short, I am wondering if there are cosmological models in the literature that has the following features:

1. Time behaves like an angle parameter
2. Particles and quantum fields are actually projections of some underlying geometric entity under different orientations